# Меню для навигации по сайту

Tags: php, javascript, html, mysql

Есть сайт, на котором админ может создавать разделы и добавлять в них материалы. Надо сделать меню:

```
Главная
--Второй уровень
---Третий уровень
----Четвертый уровень
--Второй уровень
--Второй уровень
```

и так далее. Вопрос, как реализовать это программно, если число разделов может постоянно изменяться? Они задаются программно в админке и адреса разделов хранятся в БД.

Адрес выглядит где-то так:

```
site.com/
--site.com/catalog/avto
---site.com/catalog/avto/
----site.com/catalog/parts/
--site.com/catalog/games
---site.com/catalog/PC
```

И так далее. По сути, в БД хранятся только имена разделов, вопрос можно ли сделать правильное дерево ссылок на этой основе. Если кто-нибудь может дать информацию, где почитать о корректном устройстве дерева ссылок - дайте знать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> По сути, в БД хранятся только имена разделов, вопрос можно ли сделать правильное дерево ссылок на этой основе.

Требуется непосредственно запись отношений ветвей дерева в той или иной форме. Классический вариант такой:

```
| id | parent | title |
|  1 |   NULL | root  |
|  2 |      1 | 1/a   |
|  3 |      2 | 2/b   |
|  4 |      1 | 1/c   |
```

В этом случае в столбец parent записывается непосредственный родитель записи (идентификатор родительской записи). Приведенный выше пример будет соответствовать такому дереву:

```
  root
  /  \
1/a  1/c
 |
2/b
```

В этом случае (если надо построить дерево целиком, и таблица не занимает какие-то гигансткие размеры) обычно получают всю таблицу разом, и потом на бэкенде восстанавливают дерево, используя эти связи. В PHP проще всего сделать так:

```
// 0. Тем или иным способом в переменную $raw записался массив записей
// 1. Ккаждый элемент записывается под его идентификатором
$hash = array();
foreach ($raw as $record) {
    $hash[$record['id']] = $record;
}
// 2. Для каждого элемента ищется родитель, в случае нахождения ссылка на элемент записывается в дочерние элементы родителя
foreach ($hash as &$record) {
    if (!$record['parent']) {
        // элементы верхнего уровня пропускаются
        continue;
    }
    $parentId = $record['parent'];
    // на всякий случае проверяется наличие такого родителя
    if (!isset($hash[$parentId])) {
        continue; // возможно, в этот момент надо кидать ошибку - в зависимости от того, насколько важен этот код
    }
    // Если массив дочерних элементов отсутствует, то он создается
    if (!isset($hash[$parentId]['children'])) {
        $hash[$parentId]['children'] = array();
    }
    // И, наконец, восстанавливается реальная связь элементов
    $hash[$parentId]['children'][] = &$record;
}
// 3. Из результирующего массива удаляются все элементы второго и нижележащих уровней, т.е. остаются только те, у которых не родителя.
foreach ($hash as $record) {
    if ($record['parent']) {
        unset($hash[$record['id']]);
    }
}
// 4. В $hash теперь должно лежать полноценное дерево.
```

После этого остается просто рекурсивно пройтись по дереву.

```
function printMenuLevel($level)
{
    echo '<ul>';
    foreach ($level as $record) {
        echo '<li>';
        echo $record['title'];
        if (isset($record['children'])) {
            printMenuLevel($record['children']);
        }
        echo '</li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
}
```

Это довольно простой пример работы "в лоб" без толковой организации, в реальной жизни все будет немного посложней, но принцип хранения данных скорее всего будет тем же. Небольшим массивам будет наплевать, конечно, но вообще три прохода массива - это не очень хорошо. NB: в данном примере ссылки на переменные имеют ключевое значение.

Answer (score 1):

Если правильно понял вопрос, то можно копнуть в сторону [jquery treetable](http://ludo.cubicphuse.nl/jquery-treetable/).

[Вот примеры его работы](http://ludo.cubicphuse.nl/jquery-treetable/#examples)

Answer (score 1):

Что касается представления древовидных данных в БД, то советую обратить внимание на метод таблицы замыканий . Его суть заключается в том, что в таблице хранится путь от каждого узла к каждому из его потомков с указанием глубины пути, включая путь узла к самому себе.

Например, если у вас есть такое дерево:

```
  a
 / \
b   c
   / \
  d   e
```

то таблица, представляющая его, будет выглядеть так:

```
родитель|потомок|путь
a        a       0
a        b       1
a        c       1
a        d       2
a        e       2
b        b       0
c        c       0
c        d       1
c        e       1
d        d       0
e        e       0
```

Преимущества метода: легко найти любого потомка любого родителя, легко найти поддерево, легко удалять и добавлять новые узлы, легко перемещать поддеревья.

Подробнее про этот метод и его сравнение с другими можно посмотреть в [этой](http://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/models-for-hierarchical-data) презентации.